# Read and write a Netcdf file using R

Tags: r, netcdf

How can I read and write the following file using R ?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/vlnrlxjs7f977zz/3B42_daily.2012.11.23.7.nc

In other words, I would like to read the "3B42_daily.2012.11.23.7.nc" file  and write with the same structure that it is written.

Best regards

Comment: Have you looked into `RNetCDF`? http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RNetCDF/RNetCDF.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Package `ncdf` have functions to do this. You should also read other Q&A on this site tagged with [netcdf](/questions/tagged/netcdf) and [r](/questions/tagged/r).
Basically to read a netcdf file:

```
library(ncdf)
a <- open.ncdf('your/path/to/your/file.nc') #that opens a connection to the file
```

Then function `get.var.ncdf` helps you extract the data, variable by variable.

The process to write one is described in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573656/creating-multi-dimensional-netcdf-in-r?rq=1).
The idea is to create dimensions first using `dim.def.ncdf` then the variables with `var.def.ncdf` and finally the file itself using `create.ncdf`.